# Eclipse doesn't show projects in package explorer

Tags: java, eclipse

I keep my workspace folder in the Dropbox folder so I can use it on different computers. Usually there isn't a problem. Today however I opened Eclipse and found it doesn't show the projects in the package explorer.

I checked and it's set to the correct workspace folder.

I tried to `Import existing projects into workspace`, but Eclipse doesn't allow importing the projects because 'they already exist in the workspace' - even though they don't appear.

Will appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you tried resetting your perspective? (from `Window/Reset Perspective`)

Comment: @SirCelsius Did now, didn't help :

Comment: Maybe try [this solution](http://letsgetdugg.com/2009/04/19/recovering-a-corrupt-eclipse-workspace/) to clear your metadata and generate new one when restarting Eclipse.

Comment: What about the drop-down menu in the project explorer -> Top Level Elements -> Projects?

Answer (score 1):

Keep your **project** files in DropBox.  You shouldn't share a workspace like that -- it will inevitably lead to issues like the one you describe.

That is, keep the project folder, along with the .project, .classpath, and .settings/ in your shared Dropbox space.  Create a **new** workspace on each computer, then "Import existing project" into each workspace, selecting your project in Dropbox, being sure to unselect "copy projects into workspace".

Answer (score 1):

***I don't have idea about using dropBox***-***BUT***-***However***

***For your question***::

`I tried to Import existing projects into workspace, but Eclipse doesn't allow importing the projects because 'they already exist in the workspace' - even though they don't appear.`

---

***Possibility***:: Projects are not in Eclipse explorer but a copy of it exists in the `workspace` folder so eclipse is not allowing you to add the projects with same name again.

---

***Solution***:: Create a new `workspace` and then use `dropbox` to import the projects.

Answer (score 0):

What you can also try is do

1. Create new General Project
2. Select in current workspace
3. Create project with name of an already existing project in your workspace

I seem to remember using this to "hydrate" already existing projects in my workspace into the eclipse package explorer.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me and it was because I inadvertently filtered out some of the files in the filters option in the Package Explorer.

Inside PackageExplorer -> Small drop down on top right side -> Filters

Un-select all and see if your files are now visible. Worked for me.